# Matomo Analytics: How to Track Multiple Click Events

Tags: javascript, onclick, analytics, matomo

I want Matomo (aka Piwik) to not just fire a single click event when a user clicks a certain link but I want it to fire two or even more click events.

That’s the code I am using:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Detail Page', 'Hero → Button: Contact Company XYZ']);">Contact Company XYZ</a>
```

This is what I want to use:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Detail Page', 'Hero → Button: Contact Company']); _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'All Contact Inquiries', 'Company XYZ', 'Contact Inquiries (Total)' ']); _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'All Contact Inquiries', 'Company XYZ', 'Hero → Button: Contact Company']);">Contact us</a>
```

So with this code

- the UX team sees how many times the hero contact button has been
  clicked compared to other buttons/links on a detail page
- the acquisition team immediately knows how many contact form submissions
  (in total) have been sent to a certain company which is featured on
  one of the company detail pages (This code need to be implemented
  behind every contact possibility on that detail page)
- the acquisition team instantly knows the number of clicks for every button/link on that company detail page.

Is there a way that Matomo generates multiple click events when a user clicks on a link?

Comment: in case you have got the answer from other sources. Please post here. I do want have the same use case.

Comment: > in case you have got the answer from other sources. Please post here. --> Unfortunately I did not find a solution.